# Azure Functions. Pricing estimation + Maximum Execution Duration

Tags: azure, azure-cost-management

I have a SharePoint Online site which contain around 50 custom lists. now we want to build some reports for the data inside the custom lists. and the best way to do so is to build some reporting tables (around 20 tables) in SharePoint online and use an Azure function which runs on a schedule basis to populate those reporting tables. The azure function will mainly get all the data from around 10 SharePoint lists, group and calculate them then populate the 20 reporting tables accordingly.

now since the system is new and we do not have that much data, i think the execution time can be less than 5 minutes, but as the data grows the execution time can get bigger. so what is the best plan for azure function to handle this? i do not think consumption plan will work as it has a a limitation of 10 minutes?

second question , let say in the future -after 5 years for example-, the execution time for the job took let say around 1.5 hours and we run this job daily at 1 am EST.. on average (i just need a rough number for example between 500-1,000 USD per month ?) what will be the cost per month we are going to pay?

Thanks